# Send order confirmation mail to email given in shipping address rather than logged in email id

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, email

I have logged in using abc@gmail.com. In checkout page, I have changed shipping email id to xtz@gmail.com in shipping address.

But, the mail is sending to abc@gmail.com. I want the mail to send to the email given in shipping address.

Comment: I'm afraid this is by design and you'd have to write an extension for this. Apparently Magento always prefers the email from your account over the email you give in the checkout